# Create stored procedure. Insert data from one table into another. Execute every new entry

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables. I need a stored procedure (or trigger) which executes every time a new entry is added to one of the tables. Takes that specific row and inserts it into another table.

I've looked around at stored procedures and somewhat see how to set up the procedure, but I can't see how to specifically execute the procedure ONLY when a new row is inserted into one of the two tables.

Table 1 (the table I want the procedure to pull from) 
Name : Reviewed_Renewal_Policy
Columns (Id, UniqClient, Client, DateCreated, InsertedBy)

These values are inserted through a different process. So, values are already there.

Table 2 (insert these values here)
Name: tblLogPolicyRenewalNotes

Execute this procedure every time a new entry is inserted into Table 1 (Reviewed_Renewal_Policy)

I could do this through C# code behind, but it's superfluous code that I can accomplish on the back end. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: This is to show what data I want inserted

```
AFTER NEW INSERT (FROM Table name Reviewed_Renewal_Policy)
COLUMNS(Id, UniqClient, Client, DateCreated, InsertedBy)
VALUES (447, 73567, 'Aspirations Inc', '2019-04-01 00:00:00.000', 'jSmith')


INTO Table Name tblLogPolicyRenewalNotes 
Values above
```

Comment: What you sound like you're after here is an `AFTER INSERT` trigger. iIf you post the DDL of your 2 tables, and show us what data you want to duplicate to your other table, we can show you how you'd write the trigger. Otherwise we can supply some pseudo-SQL which you could adjust to fit your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what you're after. We don't have true DDL, so if there are any column names that need correcting, you'll need to fix those:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DuplicateInsert ON dbo.Reviewed_Renewal_Policy 
AFTER INSERT AS BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.tblLogPolicyRenewalNotes(Id, UniqClient, Client, DateCreated, InsertedBy)
    SELECT Id, UniqClient, Client, DateCreated, InsertedBy
    FROM inserted;

END;
```

Obviously you can rename the trigger to something else.